# How to save multidimensional array to a flat text file - PHP

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array, currently it's only printing the array on the page. I want to be able to save it in a flat text file storing the selected checkbox information when the user submits it. There are 6 days in total.

Comment: [`serialize`](http://php.net/serialize) it

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós or better yet [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) it, so you can easily read it in other languages, too

Comment: `file_put_contents('path/to/your/file', json_encode($_POST));`

Comment: you can use json_encode

Comment: Which is the purpose of that storage? Its for serialization, or want to distribute it, so others users can consume?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd simply do this:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST)
    {//always check, to avoid noticed
        file_put_contents('theFilenameToWriteTo.json', json_encode($_POST));
    }
?>
```

The benefit of `json_encode` is that it's more or less standard. All languages that I know of can parse this format. If you're using node.js, it can read the data, Java? [JSON-java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java) is there for you. Python? [`import json`](http://pymotw.com/2/json/), hell, [even C++](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) libs are easy to find.
To reuse that data in PHP:

```
$oldPost = json_decode(file_get_contents('theFileNameToRead.json'));
//$oldPost will be an instance of stdClass (an object)
//to get an assoc-array:
$oldPostArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('sameFile.json'), true);
```

There are other options to: `serialize` and write, followed by `unserialize` on read.
If you want that array to be copy-pastable into existing PHP code, [use `var_export`](http://www.php.net/var_export)

```
file_put_contents('theArray.txt', var_export($_POST, true));
```

If you open the file then, it'll contain an array as though it were written by hand:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
)
```

As Carlos Campderrós pointed out, you can even include strings generated by `var_export`. It's important to note that `var_export` doesn't handle circular references, though, but seeing as you're using a `$_POST` array, that's not an issue here
To recap, a list of useful functions:

- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
- [`export_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)
- [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
- [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)
- [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: +1 I was writing practically the same, you have saved me a lot of work ;-). Just add that you can read the `var_export`'ed code with an `include` or `require` :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use the

```
print_r($multiArray,true)
```

The true means we want to capture the output and not print.

Array (PHP 5.4 )

```
$multiArray = [
        0 => [ 'a' => 'b'],
        1 => [ 'c' => 'd', 
               'e' => [
                   'f' => 'g',
                   'h' => 'i'
               ]
        ],
];
```

PHP

```
$file = 'array.txt';

$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");  

fwrite($fh, print_r($multiArray,true));

fclose($fh);
```

Or you could use the serialize() and unserialize() if you want to use the array later

```
fwrite($fh, serialize($multiArray) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode(), convert the array into string and store it. You can also convert back from string to array using json_decode().